# Recursion in - (void)layoutSubviews in iOS7 But works fine in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am stuck in a strange issue.
I have a view on which i have added autolayout. And inside that view there are few labels which are subclass of UILabel.
Inside that subclass i override function `- (void)layoutSubviews` (the function itself is empty)
Now the problem is that sometimes the `- (void)layoutSubviews` function called multiple times.

the stack trace of the same is as follows.

```
`#1 0x00824964 in -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] ()
 #2 0x01f4682b in -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] ()
 #3 0x01c1045a in -[CALayer layoutSublayers] ()
 #4 0x01c04244 in CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) ()
 #5 0x01c040b0 in CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) ()
 #6 0x01b6a7fa in CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) ()
 #7 0x01b6bb85 in CA::Transaction::commit() ()
 #8 0x01b6c258 in CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) ()
 #9 0x0296436e in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#10 0x029642bf in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#11 0x02942254 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#12 0x029419d3 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#13 0x029417eb in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#14 0x04b785ee in GSEventRunModal ()
#15 0x04b7842b in GSEventRun ()
#16 0x007b5f9b in UIApplicationMain () `
```

Now i am not able to understand from where it is getting called as stack trace is not showing anything. 
Can anyone help to track down the origin of the recursion here.

EDIT:- It seems like the issue with autolayouts. If i remove the autolayout from the view there is no more sublayout issue exists. Any suggestion why this is happening.

Comment: You must call `[super layoutSubviews];` inside your overridden implementation of `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: @rmaddy already tried that thing as well. But not working. Still wondering from where this layoutSubviews is called recursively.

Comment: Where is the recursion? The stack trace you posted doesn't show the recursion you mention. And post some relevant code.

Comment: @rmaddy this is the stack when i put the breakpoint in layoutsubviews and breakpoint got hit.

Comment: Please see the edited comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like an issue with autolayout. 
Whenever i use the autolayout with aspect ratio on the view the problem appears.
Remove the aspect ratio from the autolayout and the issue get solved for me.